# When accessing the page with gwt it is blank, it does not load

Tags: gwt

When I access the web page, it remains blank. I tried different browsers, even on different computers, and they all showed the same problem. I am using the gwt-2.8.2 SDK Until a few days ago, was it working correctly?
The curious thing is that the website works locally, that is, it is normally displayed in the browser, but when the project is uploaded it is not displayed.

I cleared the cache, changed the browser, and also changed the PC (even in a different geographic location). I also tried with GWT version 2.9.0

Comment: Are there any error messages or warnings in the server logs when you try to access the website on your browser?